# Issue with money order for Canadian visa

Tags: visas, canada

my visa was approved and I had sent my passport for the visa seal. But I entered wrong recipient for the money order (transfer fee of 19.9USD) and they returned my passport without visa. I can send it again, but the problem is it is more than 30 days since they asked for the passport, and they require the passport to be sent within 30 days. Anyone else faced this issue? What should I do now? Resend anyway? Or apply again? I tried to call the number in their website ((888) 296-4511), but no one responds.